# how to use jquery datetimepicker to send selected date to controller in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Jquery Date Picker, the date is selected from the DatePicker but i dont know how send or attach that date with my model, so that it can transfer to the controller. As

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
</div>
 <div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.SecretVoucherId) %>
</div>
 <div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.SecretVoucherId) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.SecretVoucherId) %>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.VoucherDate) %>
</div>

  <%-- here i have Jquery Date Picker, How to send this Selected date to Controller with model --%>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" ></p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Voucher" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this, i have to bind datepicker to the class instead of id, so that it can be reused as :

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $(".datepicker").datepicker();
     });

 <%: Html.TextBox("VoucherDate", Model.VoucherDate, New With {Key .class = "datepicker"})%>
```

Comment: Nice one, the default '#' will bind datepicker to the id whereas '.' will bind it to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `<%: Html.EditorFor(Model.VoucherDate) %>` (no need the `Function(model)` part) if you set your model correctly with `@model` and use the capital `M` as `Model` and not `model`.

And then, use the name `$("#VoucherDate")` in your javascript call instead of `$("#datapicker")`

But I would probably use a class instead of `id` so you can easily have multiple datepickers in the same page without rewrite the javascript.

use this instead:

```
@Html.TextBox("VoucherDate", Model.VoucherDate, new { @class = "datapicker" })
```

and in your javascript call change `#` into `.` so `$("#datapicker")` will be `$(".datapicker")`

---

**As a note:** you need to have the `name` attribute in your HTML in order to be passed into the controller as a property (Model or a simple property).

as an example:

This will never pass the `datepicker` to the controller :

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

this will:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" >
```

imagining that the controller is:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(DateTime datepicker) { ... }
```